# CRUD using angularJS and webAPI

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to perform CRUD using angularJS and webAPI using EF database first approach but I got blank page when i ran project, i even found issue but dont know how to solve it..

issue is realted to database connectivity..

I have following method for listing in my api controller,

```
[ActionName("get"), HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Person> Persons()
    {
        return db.Persons.ToList();
    }
```

when i put debugger and debug this method i Got = base = {"This operation requires a connection to the 'master' database. Unable to create a connection to the 'master' database because the original database connection has been opened and credentials have been removed from the connection string. Supply an unopened..." and further "childrens can not be evaluated" error.

here is my connection string :

```
 <connectionStrings>
<add name="PersonDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=PCA74\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Practice:User ID=sa;Password=db123@" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

any ideas?

Comment: I've added the [asp.net-web-api] tag to this, it's not an angular problem if your backend can't connect to the database.

Comment: Try to create `DbContext` instance i.e. `db` each time, when you call this action: `using(var db = new MyContext()){ return db.Persons.ToList(); }`